# What exactly import will do in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a python file `a.py` like this:

```
x = 1
def hello():
   print x

hello()
```

When I do `import a`, it is printing the value of `x`

Till now my understanding is `import` will include the variables and function definitions but why it is executing the method `hello()`?

Comment: you call `hello()` function your self

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python imports are not trivial, but in short, when a module gets imported, it is executed **top to bottom**. Since there is a call to hello, it will call the function and print hello.

For a deeper dive into imports, see:

- http://pyvideo.org/video/1707/how-import-works
- http://pyvideo.org/video/671/getting-the-most-out-of-python-imports

To be able to use a file both standalone and as a module, you can check for `__name__`, which is set to `__main__`, when the program runs standalone:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

See also: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 4):

In Python, there is no clear separation between declaring and executing. In fact, there are only execution statements. For example, `def hello():...` is just a way to assign a function value to the module variable `hello`. All the statements in the module are executed in their order once the module is imported.

That's why they often use guards like:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
   # call hello() only when the module is run as "python module.py"
   hello()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have called hello() function at the bottom, so when you do "import a" it will execute that function!

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the `hello()` at the end, that is what is executing the function. You only want the declarations in your file `a.py`